# How can I find a table in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2016

How can I find a table in SQL Server 2016?

I could use this to find the table in the current database:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.Tables
WHERE name LIKE '%App_Current_Seq_Num%'
```

The problem is, I have several databases on the server.

Comment: just `EXISTS dbo.Product`

Answer (score 0):

You can either do

```
use your_database_name

SELECT *
FROM sys.Tables
WHERE name LIKE '%App_Current_Seq_Num%'
```

or

```
 SELECT *
 FROM your_database_name.sys.Tables
 WHERE name LIKE '%App_Current_Seq_Num%'
```

or if you want to search multiple databases at once use a `union all` clause.
Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM database1.sys.Tables
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM database2.sys.Tables
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below sql query.

```
select * from [YourDatabaseName].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_NAME LIKE '%App_Current_Seq_Num%'
```

Answer (score 0):

`sp_tables` , `sys.tables` , `information_schema.tables` will only give you the list of tables from current selected database. Use the below undocumented stored procedure to run this code for each database, with each resultset showing the list of tables belonging to it.

```
 sp_MSforeachdb 'SELECT "?" AS DB, * FROM [?].sys.tables WHERE name like ''%App_Current_Seq_Num%'''
```

Another option is to use dynamic SQL .

Answer (score 0):

I used this and it worked perfectly:

USE Master
GO
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb
@command1='use ?; SELECT *
 FROM sys.tables
 WHERE name LIKE ''%App_Current_Seq_Num%'''

Answer (score 0):

you can use `SQL Search`

it is a simple search control that you can use in sql server

to find tables/views/stored procedures and etc...

use fast free download from

https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/index